# how can I split a dataframe into different df and need to save in different file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var df = sparkSession.read
     .option("delimiter", delimiter)
     .option("header", true) // Use first line of all files as header
     //      .schema(customSchema)
     .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
     .format("csv")
     .load(filePath)
    df.show()
    df.write.partitionBy("outlook").csv("output/weather.csv")
```

but the output saved without that column values :
for example :

```
hot,high,false,yes
cool,normal,true,yes
```

Expected output for overcast file is:

```
overcast,hot,high,false,yes
overcast,cool,normal,true,yes
```

Comment: please, provide sample input file

Answer (score 0):

When you partition your data to write it, spark creates subfolders respecting the HDFS partitioning standards. Here you'll get a subfolder for each "outlook" value found in the dataset. All the files in the "outlook=overcast" subdirectory will only concern the records for which the outlook is overcast. So no need to store the outlook column in your data, its value would be the same across the whole files in a same subdirectory.

When reading back your data through Hive or Spark for instance, you'll have to specify that the outlook subdirectories are partitions indeed so a logical column can be used for projection, grouping, filtering or whatever you want to do.

In spark this can be expressed by specifying the basePath option :

```
val df = spark.read.option("basePath", "output/weather.csv").csv("output/weather.csv/*")
```

If you really need to store the outlook column in each file then maybe partitioning is not what you need.

Comment: yes I want the entire data  with respect to that column including overcast . i am trying to make one filesplitter . There I ca specify one or two columns and based on that column values its grouped into several files and store .

Comment: Ok, I guess you need to create an extra column to partition on it : df.withColumn("outlookpart", $"outlook").write.partitionBy("outlookpart").csv("output/weather")

Comment: thats not possible  . if grouping with two columns i need to copy same with that column also.